# OVR Gaze Pointer Ring jitters when Application runs on Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am using Oculus VR toolkit to build a Unity3D Application for Gear VR. I followed [the given tutorial](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/unitys-ui-system-in-vr/) to setup my UI. But `Gaze Pointer Ring` provided with in the toolkit jitters when I try to move head a bit faster.

I also tried to add a small cube as child of OVRCameraRig at certain distance in z axis to make it visible and it has same behaviour. At first I thought that jitters in Gaze Pointer Ring is due to nun-optimised code but child of camera Object which is supposed to move smooth along with parents movement has the same problem.

Has anyone faced the same problem earlier?